# How to run libxd "Quick Start" example

Tags: c++, graphics2d

I found this graphical library in C++ called `libxd`, but the instructions are not clear for me. The quick start example is not working, I get this error in terminal `cannot find -lglad / -lglfw3 / -lrt / -ldl / -lX11` . When I was following the compiling steps, I was able to run the examples, only in Ubuntu, but the project structure was weird, very different with the quick start example .

Library link : https://bernhardfritz.github.io/libxd/#/quickstart?id=windows

Screenshot : https://postimg.cc/8742pP88

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the commands in the troubleshooting section?

> Use the following commands to check which packages you are missing:
>
> ```
> $  dpkg -l build-essential
> $  dpkg -l libgl1-mesa-dev
> $  dpkg -l xorg-dev
> ```
>
> Depending on which packages you are missing use the following commands to install them:
>
> ```
> $ sudo apt-get install build-essential
> $ sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
> $ sudo apt-get install xorg-dev
> ```